# Python fit K distribution (defined by me) on data

Tags: python, statistics

I have a sample distribution of data which I would like to fit with some not Python embedded statistics in scipy.stats, such as the K pdf.
Is it then possible to do so? Are there, by chance other modules that have the k distribution or other not gaussian pdfs available?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The conventional way to fit a distribution to data is the method of maximum likelihood. You need to be able to define the log-likelihood function (i.e. sum of log p(x_i | a)) and then you can apply any maximization algorithm to it.

Comment: I would have liked something already implemented in python for a general distribution. For many distributions included in scipy.stats, such as normal, lognormal and many others, there is the method fit which can be applied in order to retrieve the parameters of the desired distribution that better fits on the samples.

Comment: i don't know of any Scipy built-in function to carry out maximum likelihood fitting for a user-specified distribution. But searching the web for "maximum likelihood Scipy" turns up various resources, e.g.: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.6002.pdf Maybe that's useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on @Robert Dodier 's comment, reading http://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.6002.pdf you'll find a recipe for Maximum Likelihood estimation, which I adapt here:

```
import scipy
import scipy.stats as sciStat
import scipy.optimize as sciOpt

def myMleEstimate(myFunc, par, data):
    def lnL_av(x, par):
        N = len(x)
        lnL = 0.
        for i in range(N):
            lnL += scipy.log(myFunc(par, x[i]))
        return lnL/N

    objFunc = lambda s: -lnL_av(data, s)
    par_mle = sciOpt.fmin(objFunc, par, disp=0)
    return par_mle
```

If you'd want to model a Rayleigh, you'd:

```
from scipy.stats import rayleigh
Rayleigh = lambda par, x: sciStat.rayleigh.pdf(x, loc=par[0], scale=par[1])
```

And estimate from your *data*:

```
estimated = myMleEstimate(Rayleigh, [0, 1], data)
```

(Here I chose 0, 1 starting parameters).

To test the last line, you could first sample a thousand data points using:

```
# parameters
params = {
    'loc': 1,
    'scale': 2
}
data = rayleigh.rvs(loc=params['loc'], scale=params['scale'], size=1000)
```

---

And yes, I understand that a K-distro is a compound of two gammas, not a Rayleigh. But sources such as [Estimating the Parameters of the K Distribution in the Intensity Domain](http://oai.dtic.mil/oai/oai?verb=getRecord&metadataPrefix=html&identifier=ADA368069) point out that it is quite difficult with ML estimation.

*So you got what you asked, a Python recipe, but this may not be what you need.*